# codename one "cn1-data-access-lib" utf-8 source

Tags: utf-8, codenameone, dao, non-ascii-characters

I wok on my first CN1 app.
I have to use sqlite database acces.  I used the cn1-data-access-lib import from json file feature. 
It works, but the file what I import is UTF-8 encoded and Includes accented characters.  The Hungarian language is just that  .
After import the accented characters became unrecognizable in emulator. 
Made an app on buidserver, the app worked fine on an android phone. The phone setted to Hungarian. 
I checked the source code. The importer class has the “public final void importJSON(InputStream is, String selector)” method which instantiate an InputStreamReader without the second (charset or charsetName) parameter.  This procedure can not be overridden. 
Is there a solution proposal?
If I could get a free hand, I would be able to use custom inporter class. This is a solution to the problems not yet known.
Best regards,
Peter

Comment: What's `importJSON` I can't find it in our sources?  Are you using the processing package `Result` class? If so it accepts a `Reader` object. So does the `JSONParser`

Comment: Hi,
This is part of my code: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4dvlnn6j8kgg3jx/sample_code.txt?dl=0)
And a sort json file what i inport: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/31v2lkbun8qwt9g/vendeg.json?dl=0)
Best regards,
Péter

Comment: What's `DAOProvider`? Notice that you can edit your question and include additional information there. You can then comment here so I'll get a notification and try to answer again

Comment: DaoProvider qualified namie is ca.weblite.codename1.db.DAOProvider. That is in the official cn1-data-access-lib. The source code You can see here: https://github.com/shannah/cn1-data-access-lib/blob/master/src/ca/weblite/codename1/db/DAOProvider.java.
Best regards,
Péter

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in DAO cn1lib: https://github.com/shannah/cn1-data-access-lib/blob/master/src/ca/weblite/codename1/db/Importer.java#L254

It uses this code:

```
Map data = parser.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

It should at least default to UTF8. I created a pull request for this: https://github.com/shannah/cn1-data-access-lib/pull/10

Steve should address it there.

Comment: Steve changed ca.weblite.codename1.db.Importer.java but CN1DataAccess.cn1lib file on the Github was not updated.
I tried the "Update Project libs" button. CodenameOne.jar has been updated, but the cn1-data-access-lib not.
Is it possible that just therefore I do not have to learn to create the library?
Learning the Codename One is also enough.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I asked him to do that https://github.com/shannah/cn1-data-access-lib/pull/10 it will take a while after he does it as this process isn't automatic